# How to plot error ellipse knowing the VCV for xx,xy,xz,yy,yz,zz

Tags: covariance, measurement-error, covariance-matrix

I would love some guidance on if it is possible to plot error ellipses knowing what the title says and how to do it. The data has to do with GPS measurements and I need the error ellipses to find the confidence level. I searched for similar questions but didn't find any, so excuse me if it is a duplicate.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is the VCV? What language are you using? Could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: VCV is the Variance-CoVariance matrix

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the error ellipses in R, you might want to use the function ellipse from the package mixtools. See the code below for an example.

```
#load package mixtools for function ellipse()
library(mixtools) 

#set a covariance matrix
M1 <- matrix(c(2, -1, -1, 3), ncol = 2) 
M2 <- matrix(c(1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), ncol = 2) 

#plot error ellipse
ellipse(mu = c(0, 0), sigma = M1, alpha = 0.05, 
type = "l",
newplot = TRUE) 
ellipse(mu = c(0, 0), sigma = M2, alpha = 0.05, 
col = "blue",
newplot = FALSE)
```